# Change of basis that preserves subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assume I have three non intersecting planes $U,V$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. How do I prove that they can be written in the form $U=\langle (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\rangle$, $V=\langle(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1) \rangle$. Sure, there is a change of basis matrix that can let me express $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ in this way but can I conclude that it sends $U$ in itself and $V$ in itself just because it's invertible and their intersection is null?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say "can I conclude that it sends $U$ in itself and $V$ in itself...?". Could you try to rephrase that?

Comment: If these planes are subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$, how do they not intersect? They both contain the zero vector, after all. Perhaps you meant that they have the trivial intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subspaces $U, V$ need not be invariant under the matrix for change of basis.

Simply take any basis $u_1,u_2$ of $U$ and $v_1,v_2$ of $V$, then $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^4$, and *with respect to this basis*, we indeed have $U=\mathrm{span}((1,0,0,0)^T,(0,1,0,0)^T)$ and $V=\mathrm{span}((0,0,1,0)^T,(0,0,0,1)^T)$.

Comment: So if A is the matrix $(u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2)$ wrt the canonical basis, in order to express U and V as requested I just apply the inverse of A to a. So the inverse of A is the change of basis matrix?

Comment: Well, yes.. for a vector $x\in\Bbb R^4$ coordinated in the new basis as $a=(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)^T$, we get $Aa=x$ and $a=A^{-1}x$.